# Determining if Input is Parquet or Flat File

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark-sql, parquet, flat-file

I am working on a Java Maven project, and I have gotten to a point where I need to determine if my input from HDFS is either a directory of CSV files or a Parquet file. From my understanding, and I could be wrong, I believe HDFS stores Parquet files as directories.

My question is, what might be a good way of determining the difference between these two potential inputs so that I can handle each of them appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hadoop FileSystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html).

If you want to check whether an `hdfsPath` is a directory or a file use [`getFileStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-):

```
Path path = new Path(hdfsPath);
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);

FileStatus fileStatus = fs.getFileStatus(path);

if (fileStatus.isFile()) {
  // .... logic for file
} else {
  // ... logic for directory
}
```

To check if the directory contains Parquet on CSV files, you can use [`listStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) method to list the files under that directory, and for each file, you can check its extension to determine its type (`.csv` or `.parquet`).